# CSS fullscreen layout with top menu and content filling remaining screen space

Tags: css, layout, mobile-browser

I want to achieve that result as my web app layout:

[image]

I create application for mobile usage first. I want to fixed top menu that stretch to it content and content at the bottom of this menu. Content height can be very long but I want to use `overflow-y: auto;`. I use CSS `display: table;` for container and `display: table-row;` for menu and content to solve this problem. JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hV5Dz/).

Which pros and cons should I expect? I.e. mobile browsers interoperability, performance issues and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue and I solved it in exactly the same way you did. The only issue I ran into was that the row on the bottom:

```
#content {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}
```

IE will not respect this and it will see height:100%; and instead of taking of the remaining space of the table like every other browser it will be equal to 100% of the entire table causing your layout to render incorrectly. The only way i found to solve this was to use a bit of jquery with a window resize function to basically only fire when it's IE and apply a pixel value height to the #content based on what it should be.

Comment: Which version of IE has this trouble? I think that height-helper div with position absolute solved it...

Comment: I had this issue in the latest version of IE still. The overall table height was overflowing the screen by exactly the height of the top cell which means it thinks that 100% isn't 100% of the remaining space but 100% of the table height. If you're not seeing the issue though than more power to you.